# Is there a way to export/import the oracle PDB into SQL script?

Tags: oracle, pdb

I have a requirement wherein I need to copy entire  PDB(which is inside oracle CDB) info from source DB system to target DB system with just SQL scripts using 1521 port. There is restriction to ssh into the DB VM.

Comment: What do you mean by SQL scripts - capturing the DDL and DML (inserts) for all objects in a readable form, then running against the target? Have you considered using data pump, [over a network link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/upgrd/migrating-data-after-upgrade-oracle.html#GUID-072AC19E-EEBF-4663-AB3A-4CFA74873C87)?

Comment: That's right. Datadump over network link will not work for me as the source has no connection to target dB.

Comment: So what are you connecting to port 1521 from? A client that can access both source and target? SQL Developer has options to export and import, maybe those would be suitable for you? I'm sure other clients do too, of course.